# Expansion of Struts 2 Tags Messes Up Rendering Of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

Often times, when I use struts 2 tags, the loading of a page will be incomplete apparently because of single quote or double quote characters from the struts 2 tag interfering with such characters from javascript.

One example I am very eager to get working is as follows:

```
 var me = '<s:a href=\'http://www.google.com\'>Google Link</s:a>';
 $('#appnSelect').html(me);
```

So what I am concerned about is when single and double quotes are inside that me string on the right side of line 1.  Ultimately, I need to get `<s:select>` to work, but this problem seems to creep in with a number of tags like the above example.  Replace the `<s:a>` tag with an `<a>` tag, and voila, it works.  However, when the `<s:a>` tag gets expanded, the page will incompletely load.

Is there an easy solution somewhere I am missing?  One thing I did try was with the theme attribute setting theme="simple" because sometimes that helps me when the output gets rendered incorrectly.  That did not work in this case.

Comment: For anything complicated setting the theme to simple is a good idea, you know exactly what you're getting.  As a matter of fact I like to set it globally in struts.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating HTML from tags like that in the middle of a JavaScript string constant is always going to be an ugly business.  In addition to quote characters, you're also likely to get newlines. Strictly speaking you don't know *what* you're going to get, and you can't control it.

One thing that comes to mind is that you could drop the tags into dummy `<script>` blocks marked as a non-JavaScript type:

```
<script id='anAnchor' type='text/html'>
  <s:a href='http://www.google.com'>Google Link</s:a>
</script>
```

The browser won't try to execute that.  You can then do this in your JavaScript code:

```
$('#appnSelect').html($('#anAnchor').html());
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  When I do the following immediately following the jQuery line `alert($('#appnSelect').html());` I get back nothing in the alert and the region in the form shows nothing.  I am using IE 7 if that turns out to be a problem (something I can't adjust).

Comment: IE7 should have no problem with it - are you sure that the "alert()" is *after* the `<script>` tag in the source, or else in a jQuery "ready" handler?  That "alert()" in your comment is looking for the "appnSelect" element, and in my example I gave the `<script>` tag the id "anAnchor".  What does `alert($('#anAnchor').html())` show?

Comment: I'm getting there slowly. Right now I have a very similar jquery line at the bottom of my page `<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#appnSelect').html( $('#anAnchor').html() ) }); </script>` This appnSelect is currently a div deeply nested in page. Then finally just after my `<body>` tag I have `<script type="text/html" id="anAnchor"> <s:a href='http://www.google.com'>Google Link</s:a></script>` This allows for my div to be populated. Now I am going to see if this works with my s:select tag. Either way, I'll give you at least a vote up at 00:00 GMT.

Comment: Unless the Struts tags themselves somehow don't like it (I don't see how they would, though some libraries do insist that their form element tags only occur inside of forms; I don't know Struts however), so I would imagine it should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

What should work with very little thinking:

```
<s:a id="google" style="display: none;" href="www.google.com">Google Link</s:a>
```

Now just grab the the element using the id in your script. Might be better if you set up a class. There are id, style and class attributes for all struts2 tags.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with your escaping of the single quotes inside the `<s:a>` tag. In my experience with using `<s:url>`, I've done the following:

```
var url = "<s:url value='/someAction.action' />"
```

I believe the same syntax should hold true for `<s:a>`.

Additionally, look in your JSP container's error log, and see if you can find an error relating to that `<s:a>` tag. That may provide some additional insight to the problem.

Comment: Actually ... that particular example does not work for me unless you put the single quote on the outside and the double quote on the inside. The reason as I see when I do view source, the inner quotes will be generated as double quotes even if I use single quotes.  I like what Pointy said: "is always going to be an ugly business"

Comment: Right - the problem is that *tags* expect that the stuff they generate is going to be parsed by the HTML (or XHTML) parser, *not* the JavaScript parser. The metacharacters for those two syntaxes are not the same; in fact they're mutually exclusive (except for quotes in HTML attributes).

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer, which will not be the best answer because Pointy's response pointed me in the correct direction.  However, up votes still appreciated :)

First, you need the script blocks which are not rendered.  I have 2 because a checkbox will toggle between which one is displayed:

```
     <script type="myType" id="abc">
   <s:select name="selectName" list="#list1" listValue="%{prefix + '-' + name}" theme="simple"/>         
 </script>
 <script type="myType" id="abc2">
   <s:select name="selectName" list="#list2" listValue="%{prefix + '-' + name}" theme="simple"/>         
 </script>
```

Next, I create a region which is blank in the html code

```
<div id="innerRegion">
                                           </div>
```

Then, I need to put something on the screen when the page first comes up, so go with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#innerRegion').html( $('#abc').html() )
});
```

I needed to put this at the end of my document because onLoad was already being used by a parent page.  So I am saying abc is the correct default.

Then I need logic to handle what happens when the checkbox is pushed:

```
   var buttonPressed = false; 

   $(window).load(
   function() 
   { 
     LocalInit();
   });

   function LocalInit() {     
   $('#myForm input[name=buttonValue]').change(
     function() 
     {
        buttonPressed = !buttonPressed;
        if (buttonPressed == true)
        {
           $('#innerRegion').html( $('#abc2').html() )
        } else
        {           
           $('#innerRegion').html( $('#abc').html() )
        }
        $('#dataId').href = document.location.href;            
     }
   );
  }
```

I think what was tripping me up ultimately was that I was trying to force the s:select tag through jQuery functions when as you see above it did not turn out to be necessary.  I could just write the s:select as normal.